# How can I make this code to count Hamiltonian paths faster?

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

I have this very basic code to count Hamiltonian paths in a graph:

```
privateCountHamiltonians = 
  Function[{vertices, current, visited}, Module[{newVisited }, (
     newVisited = Append[visited, current];
     If[
      Length[newVisited] == Length[vertices],
      1,
      Total[ Map[
        If[! MemberQ[newVisited, #], 
          privateCountHamiltonians[vertices, #, newVisited], 0] &, 
        vertices[[current]]
        ]]
      ])
    ]];

makeVertices[edges_] := Module[{list}, (
    list = ConstantArray[{}, Max[edges]];
    Scan[Function[edge, (
       AppendTo[list[[edge[[1]]]], edge[[2]]];
       AppendTo[list[[edge[[2]]]], edge[[1]]];
       list
       )], edges];
    list
    )];

countHamiltonians[edges_] := Module[{vertices}, (
    vertices = makeVertices[edges];
    Total[
     Map[privateCountHamiltonians[vertices, #, {}] &, 
      Range[1, Length[vertices]]]]
    )];
```

The `edges` argument must have the form `{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, ...}` where each item inside represents an edge. The bottleneck is `privateCountHamiltonians` since is where recursion occurs. I thought using Combinatorica's `HamiltonianPath` would be more effective, but surprisingly that one is way slower than mine, at least on not so big graphs, as per this code:

```
<< Combinatorica`
g = Combinatorica`GridGraph[2, 4];
Timing[countHamiltonians[Combinatorica`Edges[g]]]
Timing[Length[Combinatorica`HamiltonianPath[g, All]]]
```

Which yielded:

```
{0.015625, 28}
{21.093750, 28}
```

I'm not hoping to implement some of the existing advanced algorithms, but since I'm new to Mathematica, I wonder if there is some simple things I'm overlooking that could make my code run faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use FindHamiltonianCycle.

To convert Hamiltonian path problem to Hamiltonian cycle problem, just add one vertex and connect it to all other vertices. After that just run FindHamiltonianCycle[g, All]

For example,

```
countHamiltonianPaths[g_] :=
 Length[
    FindHamiltonianCycle[
       AdjacencyGraph[PadRight[AdjacencyMatrix[g], (VertexCount[g] + 1) {1, 1}, 1]], 
    All]
 ]
```

Test:

```
g = GridGraph[{4, 5}];

AbsoluteTiming[countHamiltonianPaths[g]]
(* {0.005012, 1006} *)
```

Note that FindHamiltonianCycle for undirected graphs doesn't consider the direction of cycles ,i.e,  {1,2,3} and {3,2,1} are regarded as the same cycles.  That's why the number is the half of your function.

Comment: This is neat. Wonder why they didn't implement it this way in combinatorica.

Comment: Nice solution, very clever.

Comment: Can you take a look at this?  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110102/12  Is it a bug?  I am not familiar with k-plexes.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same basic algorithm but in my own style. It runs only about twice as fast as yours, but hopefully it will be of interest anyway.

The recursive function `count` maintains the current vertex, the adjacency list $a$ and a counter $i$. At each call the current vertex is removed from the adjacency list and the function recursively scanned over the available next vertices. The counter starts at $n$ (the number of vertices) and decreases by 1 on each recursive call, so when it hits 1 a Hamiltonian path has been completed. I use `Sow` and `Reap` to collect the paths.

`mycount` is the main function. Note that I have written it to work with built-in `Graph` expressions (not combinatorica) and I'm using `AdjacencyMatrix` to get the adjacency list.

```
count[current_, a_, i_] := Module[{b = DeleteCases[a, current, {2}]},
        Scan[count[#, b, i - 1] &, b[[current]]]; 0]

count[_, _, 1] := Sow[1]

mycount[g_Graph] := Module[{a, n},
  a = AdjacencyMatrix[g]["AdjacencyLists"];
  n = Length[a];
  Total[Reap[count[#, a, n] & /@ Range[n]], -1]]
```

Testing:

```
g = GridGraph[{4, 5}];

AbsoluteTiming[mycount[g]]
(* {3.73159, 2012} *)

AbsoluteTiming[countHamiltonians[List @@@ EdgeList[g]]]
(* {7.39043, 2012} *)
```

Comment: This was really helpful, but I hope you don't mind I'm changing the accepted answer since that version is a lot faster.

Comment: I don't mind at all, it's a much better solution.